# Does Google Plus iOS SDK support arm64?

Tags: ios, iphone, google-plus

I'm working with google plus and I've met next problem.
When I run my app on my iPhone 4 - it's working good. But when I'm trying make a build or run it on arm64-simulator - it's crashing, 'cause no valid architecture. When I've remove arm64 in architecture list and set NO to Built valid archs only, it send a warning message that lib doesn't support i386. I've checked info via terminal with command `lipo -info libGooglePlus.a` and there is no arm64 in the list, but i386 exist.

So I have a question. Does G+ iOS SDK support arm64 architecture? Really after 6 months google doesn't support this architecture? Or maybe you have another solution?

Comment: Google plus iOS SDK is an open source project. you will get the source code get it, create a static library that supports arm64 also

Comment: And how can I do that? O.o

Comment: Do you know how to create a static library in ios

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-static-library-in-ios-tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Which version of the SDK did you use? arm64 has been supported since the 1.4.0 release of the SDK, which was shortly after the release of iOS 7.

Supported architectures from the current 1.5.0 version:

```
Architectures in the fat file: GooglePlus are: armv7 armv7s i386 x86_64 arm64
```

Comment: Doesnt seem to support x86_64 in my case for the latest 1.7.1 version

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31758580/latest-google-plus-ios-sdk-1-7-1-not-supporting-architecture-x86-64

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using an old version of the SDK. Please, upgrade by downloading the latest SDK [here](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/upgrading-sdk)